# Java Socket Programming: Send Object as CSV or Serialized Object?

Tags: java, sockets, csv, network-programming, objectoutputstream

I am just getting in to writing networked code using Sockets in Java. I'm just making some test programs. Originally I was going to send data as comma separated values, but I recently discovered ObjectOutputStream. Which method would be faster or more bandwidth efficient? For example, if I'm making a game where I have to send x and y coordinates very often, should I send it through PrintWriter separated by a comma, or make a Position class and send an instance over ObjectOutputStream. What if I change my code and need to send a lot more data?

What are the pros and cons of sending data as CSV over PrintWriter vs as fields in an object over ObjectOutputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ad-hoc binary format has a good chance of being more bandwidth-efficient than the default serialization format, which should be (but it's a wild guess, and it depends on the nature and amount of data: you should **measure** it if it matters) more or less as bandwidth efficient than a text-based format.

But bandwidth efficiency is not the only thing that matters.

Using serialization, the client and the server must be written in Java, and have the classes of the serialized objects in their classpath. If you intend to have clients written in any language, you shouldn't consider it.

If serialization is OK, it's of course a really easy way to transform almost any Java object into bytes, which allows you to avoid defining a format.

Note that there are alternatives that provide almost the same flexibility, but don't have the Java-only disadvantage of serialization. For example, JSON, XML, or [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

Answer (score 0):

I think CSV is smaller.

If you want to check data size,please try to output to a File.

and I don't recommend ObjectOutputStream to you by other reason.

Because you have to keep Objects compatibility.

Did you research about serialize and serialVersionUID?

Please check [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)